# Error when running redshift query through AWS sdk from a lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift-serverless

I have a problem when I try to run Redshift query from a AWS lambda function by using the AWS sdk `@aws-sdk/client-redshift-data`.
I have a Redshift serverless cluster.

This error is returned:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1487:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 80,
  '$metadata': { attempts: 1, totalRetryDelay: 0 }
}
```

Here is my lambda:

```js
  const client = new RedshiftData({
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
    endpoint: process.env.REDSHIFT_HOST
  })

  try {
    console.log('Send executeStatementCommand...')
    let queryStatus: StatusString | string | undefined
    const output: ExecuteStatementCommandOutput = await client.executeStatement({
      Sql: sql,
      Database: process.env.REDSHIFT_DATABASE,
      WorkgroupName: process.env.REDSHIFT_WORKGROUPNAME
    })
...
```

I don't know why the address is `127.0.0.1`...
Maybe (certainly haha), I do something wrong but I don't really know

Anyone has already encountered this problem or has any advice?

Some help will be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem.
The endpoint parameter of any of AWS SDK client including RedshiftData in this case, is always AWS API endpoints.
It must be empty in my case.